# NAudio pcm record with "winmm.dll" - Casual "AccessViolationException" on waveInPrepareHeader

Tags: c#, multithreading, naudio, .net-7.0

My application (.NET 7), sometimes crash when I'm trying to start recording using NAudio WaveIn with the following error

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
> Stack:
> at NAudio.Wave.WaveInterop.waveInPrepareHeader(IntPtr, NAudio.Wave.WaveHeader, Int32)
> at NAudio.Wave.WaveInterop.waveInPrepareHeader(IntPtr, NAudio.Wave.WaveHeader, Int32)
> at NAudio.Wave.WaveInBuffer.Reuse()
> at NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent.DoRecording()
> at NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent.RecordThread()
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()

This is how i start the recording on user interaction;

```
if (this.PcmWaveIn == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PcmWaveIn init started...");

    this.PcmWaveIn = new WaveInEvent
    {
        DeviceNumber = 0,
        WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(rate: 8000, bits: 16, channels: 1),
        BufferMilliseconds = 20
    };

    this.PcmWaveIn.DataAvailable += (object? sender, WaveInEventArgs e) =>
    {
        // copy buffer into an array of integers
        Int16[] values = new Int16[e.Buffer.Length / 2];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(e.Buffer, 0, values, 0, e.Buffer.Length);

        // Perform A-law encoding
        byte[] alawData = new byte[e.Buffer.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Buffer.Length; i += 2)
        {
            short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, i);
            alawData[i / 2] = NAudio.Codecs.ALawEncoder.LinearToALawSample(sample);
        }
        // Do things....
    };

    Console.WriteLine("PcmWaveIn init complete...");
}
this.PcmWaveIn.StartRecording();
```

And then simply stop with: `this.PcmWaveIn?.StopRecording();`

I always leave the application running, and this issue sometimes occurs on the same day I start the software, or sometimes after a week or a few days. The application also makes extensive use of multithreading. Could this affect how the library manages resources?
If so, how can I be sure to avoid `AccessViolationException` on a multithreading environment?

I was thinking to make a service in order to manage the NAudio library start/stop recording with some lock logic, can be usefull?

Comment: Such memory corruption problems are always hard to diagnose, gets a lot worse when threading is involved.  Just keep in mind that the corruption is probably far removed from the code that crashes.